# How to clear the data from ajax without reloading the page?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a loop that executes an ajax and inside that ajax is another ajax, they are both inside a loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < SomeLength; i ++) {
 $.ajaxFileUpload ({ #this is a plugin
   url : 'some perl url',
   ....
   .....
   ......
   success : function (data) {
     $.ajax({
       myconcatinatedHTML += 'Some auto generated HTML template';
     });
   }
 });
}
```

After the loop I will put the value of `myconcatenatedHTML` inside a dialog box.

```
$(".tech-file-upload-dialog").html( myconcatenatedHTML ); #this is the dialog box.
```

But I had problem displaying it because of async issue, so I ended up putting the dialog box inside:

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
 $(".tech-file-upload-dialog").html( myconcatenatedHTML );
});
```

It fixed the issue, but generated again another which is it always appends INCREMENTALLY the value of `myconcatenatedHTML` if I dont reload the page first.

ex: if the value of `myconcatenatedHTML` is `foo` at first, second time the ajax executes (without reloading the page), `myconcatenatedHTML` will be `foo foo` which is not what i wanted.

Is there a way to clear the value of `myconcatenatedHTML` after it fires that dialog box?

Comment: What do you think `+=` operator does? `myconcatinatedHTML += 'Some auto generated HTML template';` --- explain what do you think this line should do.

Comment: it concatinates, is that sarcasm?

Comment: it's not. So you realize that you're concatenating a string you already have with a new one. Do you?

Comment: yes, that's what i wanted to do, actually it will put new tr to my table. What seems to be the problem there sir?

Comment: so you're concatenating but you don't want to concatenate. Right?

Comment: "which is not what i wanted." --- from the question. "that's what i wanted to do" --- from the comment above.

Comment: I want to concatinate it, but after it is displayed in the dialog box, i want it cleared so that i can concatinate a new table again

Comment: "clear" is just assigning an empty string, isn't it?

Comment: yes, i tried assigning an empty string to it, but seems like ajaxStop fires all the time, so it cant be cleared through just assigning empty string

Comment: So clear it before the start of the loop, instead of in the `ajaxStop` handler?

Answer (score -1):

You should clear the variable here as follows.

```
success : function (data) {
myconcatinatedHTML  = "" //clearing the variable;
     $.ajax({
       myconcatinatedHTML += 'Some auto generated HTML template';
     });
   }
```

Comment: Why not use `=` instead?

Comment: Syntactically it's wrong. You can't use `+=` in an object in that way.

Comment: @zerkms This line `{
       myconcatinatedHTML += 'Some auto generated HTML template';
     }`

Comment: @undefined: yep. Now I see.

Comment: But i dont want it cleared on success because ajax will succeed many times ( it is inside a loop) i want it cleared outside the loop. **Note that setting the variable to an empty string doesnt work too.

Comment: @BelmarkCaday you can clear the variable just outside your loop.